# OpenCV FeatureDetector doesn't seem to set various properties after reading it from file

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

Following is the code to detect blob/moles in colored skin image using Java and OpenCV 3.0

```
private void initLibService(){

    String opencvpath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator;
    System.load(opencvpath + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME + ".dll");

    blobDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIMPLEBLOB);

    try {
        File temp = File.createTempFile("tempFile",".tmp");
        String settings="%YAML:1.0\nthresholdStep: " + Integer.parseInt(ResourceUtil.getProperty("MOLE_THRESHOLD_STEPS")) + "\nminThreshold: "+ Integer.parseInt(ResourceUtil.getProperty("MOLE_UPPER_INTENSITY_THRESOLD")) + "\n";
        System.out.println("\nFeature detector setting data: " + settings + "\n\n");

        FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(temp,false);
        writer.write(settings);
        writer.close();

        blobDetector.read(temp.getPath());

        temp.deleteOnExit();
      }
     catch (  IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

public static Mat detectBlob(String imagePath, FeatureDetector blobDetector) {

    // Read image
    Mat im = Imgcodecs.imread(imagePath);

    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    blobDetector.detect(im, keypoints);
    System.out.println("keypoints: " + keypoints.toList());

    Mat im_with_keypoints = new Mat();
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    return im_with_keypoints;
}
```

If I comment the line `blobDetector.read(temp.getPath());` then the attached skin image is being marked with circles around some moles (may be using some default property values of featuredetector), but If I didn't, nothing get marked on the image.

[image]

Comment: Apology for not adding the image

Comment: Why do you think that the `FeatureDetector` will read your custom YAML? If you use `read` to load not properly formatted data, it won't work.

Comment: @Miki can you please suggest a way to create valid custom YAML for the same. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify all properties in your file, or the detector will be loaded incorrectly.

Your file should look like this (default values):

```
%YAML:1.0
thresholdStep: 10.
minThreshold: 50.
maxThreshold: 220.
minRepeatability: 2
minDistBetweenBlobs: 10.
filterByColor: 1
blobColor: 0
filterByArea: 1
minArea: 25.
maxArea: 5000.
filterByCircularity: 0
minCircularity: 8.0000001192092896e-001
maxCircularity: 3.4028234663852886e+038
filterByInertia: 1
minInertiaRatio: 1.0000000149011612e-001
maxInertiaRatio: 3.4028234663852886e+038
filterByConvexity: 1
minConvexity: 9.4999998807907104e-001
maxConvexity: 3.4028234663852886e+038
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have tried above settings with FeatureDetector.SIMPLEBLOB where it is not working but when I try the same with FeatureDetector.FAST, it seems to work ? If the settings are not applicable for SIMPLEBLOB?

Comment: Oh It is working if I use the existing code to write yaml temp file and include all above mentioned parameters.... Thanks a lot Miki